# R data into panel data

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, data-wrangling

I have several datasets which look roughly like this ones.
I would like to transform into a proper panel dataset to run regressions and random forests.

However, I am struggling to put the years into a column. Thank you very much in advance

First column: Country Second column: Year Third: consumption expenditure Fourth: Household consumption

[image: Picture of one of my datasets]

Answer (score 2):

`tidyr`'s `pivot_` functions should do the trick

```
library(tidyverse)

data_raw <- ... # import data

panel <- data_raw %>%
  pivot_longer(1970:1984, names_to = 'year')
```